# Understanding active voice (object/subject)

Tags: ellipsis, transitivity

Consider the sentence.

> The strains on your jacket **won't come out**.

Here, come out is an active-voice verb. But what is the object and what is the subject for that verb? I'd guess the object here is the strains. Since the object does, but subject recieves the object's action I'd guess that the object (strains) does the action (come out), but it seems completely nonsensical to me. How can the strains do the action ever? Maybe I have wrong understanding about object/subject concepts?

Couldn't you explain?

Comment: This dog won't hunt.   The verb is intransitive.    This color won't fade.

Comment: Do you mean "strains" (lengthening, shortening, buckling, puckering, or tearing)?  Or do you mean "stains" (unwanted blotches of color)?

Comment: Google for subject and object. There are hundreds of websites that explain those simple grammar terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But what is the object and what is the subject for that verb?

There's no object, but *strains* is the subject.
The strains on your jacket will not come out anybody/anything.

Comment: So we should have used passive voice instead?

Comment: Who/what will come out by the strains on your jacket? The strains on your jacket will come out by who/what?